# Apex scope for creating temporary sObjects

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

I have a trigger that creates child objects on insert/update. The update trigger has logic based on a field on the parent object. Depending on this field, it may create 1 or 2 child objects. When I try to create both objects outside of my IF statement, I receive a nullPointerException error. I would like to create both temporary objects outside of my IF statements in order to save space, but it seems to not be working:

Successful code:

```
if (trigger.isupdate) {
        set<id> ids = new set<id>();
        list<targeting_allocation__c> toInsert = new list<targeting_allocation__c>();
        for(opportunity o: trigger.new) {
            if (o.id != null) {
                if (o.program_type__c != trigger.oldmap.get(o.id).program_type__c) {
                   ids.add(o.id);
                }
            }
        }


        for(opportunity o: [select id, program_type__c from opportunity where id in :ids]) {
            targeting_allocation__c x = new targeting_allocation__c ();
            x.allocation_opportunity__c = o.id;
            x.Allocation_Percent__c = 100;
            x.Program_Type__c = o.program_type__c;
            if (o.program_type__c == 'MMA Balanced') {
                targeting_allocation__c child2 = new targeting_allocation__c ();
                child2.allocation_opportunity__c = o.id;
                child2.Allocation_Percent__c = 50;
                child2.Program_Type__c = 'MMA nSpire';
                x.Allocation_Percent__c = 50;
                x.Program_Type__c = 'MMA mPower';
                toInsert.add(x); toInsert.add(child2);
            } else {
                toInsert.add(x);
            }
        }
        try {
            delete [select id from targeting_allocation__c where allocation_opportunity__c in :ids];
            insert toInsert;
        } catch (system.DmlException e) {
            system.debug(e);
        }
    }
```

Unsuccessful code:

```
if (trigger.isupdate) {
        set<id> ids = new set<id>();
        list<targeting_allocation__c> toInsert = new list<targeting_allocation__c>();
        for(opportunity o: trigger.new) {
            if (o.id != null) {
                if (o.program_type__c != trigger.oldmap.get(o.id).program_type__c) {
                   ids.add(o.id);
                }
            }
        }


        for(opportunity o: [select id, program_type__c from opportunity where id in :ids]) {
            targeting_allocation__c x, y = new targeting_allocation__c ();
            x.allocation_opportunity__c = o.id; y.allocation_opportunity__c = o.id;
            x.Allocation_Percent__c = 100; y.Allocation_Percent__c = 100;
            x.Program_Type__c = o.program_type__c; y.Program_Type__c = o.program_type__c;
            if (o.program_type__c == 'MMA Balanced') {
                y.Allocation_Percent__c = 50;
                y.Program_Type__c = 'MMA nSpire';
                x.Allocation_Percent__c = 50;
                x.Program_Type__c = 'MMA mPower';
                toInsert.add(x); toInsert.add(y);
            } else {
                toInsert.add(x);
            }
        }
        try {
            delete [select id from targeting_allocation__c where allocation_opportunity__c in :ids];
            insert toInsert;
        } catch (system.DmlException e) {
            system.debug(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not certain how the first example saves you space. If anything, I would suggest that the first would be more efficient when only `x` is needed, as you don't bother instantiating (using more memory) the second variable, except when the conditions require it. Unless I'm completely missing something.

Comment: On which line is the NullPointerException being thrown? Do you have a debug log?

Comment: Hi Peter, the second one is meant to save space, not the first. It was the "insert toInsert;" line that threw the exception. Enreeco found the error below...turns out I never actually instantiated x as a new object. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "targeting_allocation__c x, y = new targeting_allocation__c ();" is missing "x" initialization.
In fact only the second variable is constructed (the "new targeting_allocation__c ()" is executed once).
So simply replace with:

```
targeting_allocation__c x, y;
x = new targeting_allocation__c();
y = new targeting_allocation__c();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was under the impression that you could instantiate multiple sObjects using the sObject x, y = new sObject(); ... I guess not, thanks for the help!